# Cannot enable guest account

Tags: macos, user-account, accounts

I cannot enable Guest Account. Logged as admin, I got at Users & Groups, select Guest User,and tick Allow guests to log on this computer. Even when ticked, "disabled" appears bellow Guest User account label. When I switch to the admin account and then back at guest account (within preferences) the box is now unchecked. Any ideas what can cause this?

p.s: I don't have FileVault

### Update

So I thought to try a restart. A guest account is has appeared and working (looked disabled before restart) but I cannot open Users & Group Prefs. When I select it I get: Could not load Users & Groups Preference Pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [David solution here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3206277?start=0&tstart=0) (although not the cause):

> I used Directory Utility (`/System/Library/Core Services/Directory Utility`) to delete two extra Guest accounts ("Guest1" and "Guest2").
>
> After deleting those two records I could open the Users & Groups System Preference Pane.

Source: [I've got "Preference Error: Could not load Users](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3206277?start=0&tstart=0)